# Android: EditText Search from arraylist

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, android-edittext

I am getting an arraylist from sqlite database that contains custom objects. I have an EditText in an Activity and what I want is to search data from that arraylist in that EditText. This is a simple activity no listview. I have done it using filterable EditText with  listview by using this code

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {                      
        ((Filterable) adapter).getFilter().filter(cs);                          
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                             }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
    }
});
```

But now here in this line `((Filterable) adapter).getFilter().filter(cs);` instead of `adapter` I have an `ArrayList` of custom objects retrieved from Database. When I run the code it give me the error of `classcast exeption` that `ArrayList` cannot be cast to `filterable`. Please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: how can an adapter be an arraylist?

Comment: It can't be. But I am really don't familiar with filterable so just for try I have did so.

Comment: @njzk2 any idea how to do this with ArrayList?

Comment: see http://guidogarcia.net/blog/2011/10/29/java-different-ways-filter-collection/